# How to remove Current added child fragment from another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments like fragment A , Fragment B, Fragment C. Initially Fragment A is loaded and Fragment A adds Fragment B , Similarly Fragment B again adds Fragment C.Now When I click backpress or any buttoms in Fragment C , it shows directly  fragment A. Why it is not showing Fragment B ? I just want to remove the current fragment c and show fragment b but how please help me .here is my code.

```
//This is FragmentA and it adds FragmentB
 fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_main,new FragmentB());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

//This is FragmentB and it adds FragmentC
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.publicCommunication,new FragmentC());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

//This is FragmentC and button is available remove cuurent fragment. now here is my problem , it removes both fragmentC and FragmentB and Shows FragmentA. I want it to show FragmentC but it is not showing it shows fragmentA.
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                 manager.popBackStackImmediate();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the activity fragment manager to pop the backstack but it does not seem this manager "propagates" the pop to children managers

Change your `onClick` code as below

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
             manager.popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you are not adding any fragment to backstack, you are only adding fragment to an activity, so you need to change this line:- **fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);** with this :-**fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("With your unique string");**

add this to your both fragment transactions.
and then commit.

Comment: hi there, Thank you for your quick respond. But i am still not able to do that even putting string value in both addtobackStack fragmentA and FragmentB .Would you please describe it more clearly..it's a kind request..thank you.

Comment: you can see you are using different managers and i think poping out from only one manager i.e FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
             manager.popBackStackImmediate();

Comment: Please have a look at this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

Instead of

```
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.popBackStackImmediate();
```

bacause, it should use only from an activity and not from fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding FragmentC in the childFragmentManager of FragmentB, you have to remove/pop the FragmentC from FragmentB's childFragmentManager (not from Activity's supportFragmentManager).

So in your Button click listener just do this -

kotlin :

```
parentFragment?.childFragmentManager?.popBackStack()
```

Java :

```
getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack()
```